# Neon : Perform Vector multiplication with a scalar value

Tags: c, linux, neon

Hi i am new to neon programming.
Looking for vector multiplication with a scalar value.
For adding two vector i was able to perform using following code.

```
void add(float* dst, float* src1, float* src2, int count)
{
    asm volatile (
    "1: \n"
    "ld1 {v0.4s}, [%[src1]], #16 \n"
    "ld1 {v1.4s}, [%[src2]], #16 \n"
    "fadd v0.4s, v0.4s, v1.4s \n"
    "subs %[count], %[count], #4 \n"
    "st1 {v0.4s}, [%[dst]], #16 \n"
    "bgt 1b \n"
    : [dst] "+r" (dst)
    : [src1] "r" (src1), [src2] "r" (src2), [count] "r" (count)
    : "memory", "v0", "v1"
    );
}
```

To perform multiplication is there any other api like fadd ?
Example :

| 3 2 | * 5  = |15 10|

Comment: Is there any good reason why you don't use intrinsics from `arm_neon.h` ?

Comment: I don't know neon but in other SIMD architectures I've encountered, you would pack the scalar value into a vector where each element is that scalar, and then multiply vectors. It wouldn't surprise me if that's how to do it in neon too, since such an operation is pretty much the lowest-hanging fruit of any vector instructions.

Comment: @tstanisl Thanks using `arm_neon.h` i was able to perform the required operation.

Comment: @paddy: that's what you would do, unless you would actually have an instruction set that has `fmul v0.4s, v1.4s, v2.4s[3]`, i.e. can multiply vector in `q1` with a single scalar at the third lane in vector `q2`. That kind of ISA makes _many_ operations faster / smaller. If I'd had the opportunity to design a SIMD ISA, I would also try to include scalar addition.

Answer (score 1):

```
float32x4_t C = vmulq_n_f32(A, B);
```

Where A is a float32x4_t and B is a float (the scalar).

Of course, you can use other data types with vmulq_n_u16 (uint16), vmulq_n_s32 (int32), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Neon intrinsics search](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D&q=fmul&first=20), as a useful guide, and then lane multiply (lane of another vector register) to get the scalar value:
FMUL Vd.4S,Vn.4S,Vm.S[lane]